# Is it possible to change format of date values in a MySQL column?

Tags: mysql, date

The database in use today was made 5 years ago and the entries in some of the date fields/columns are in a european string format, diplaying 29.05.2013 instead of 2013-05-29, the last one somewhat of a standard.

Regret the setup today, but it was done this way years ago due to lack of knowledge on the subject.

Is it possible to rewrite these column values? 
Or as a second solution, perhaps taking data from the old column and writing them to a new column while doing the transition?

Every row has a unique ID - `testid`

Database looks like this:

```
    testid        date1        date2        date3
    --------------------------------------------------
    001           2012-01-01   02.01.2012   04.01.2012
    002           2012-03-03   05.03.2012   10.03.2012
```

In `date1` we're using timestamp, so it works fine. Would really like to have the other columns in the same format.

Hoping that someone with better know-how than myself have some suggestions.

Comment: What are the types of your columns? Esp. `date2` and `date3`? Strings? Oh, I see. It's `date/char(10)/char(10)` or sth. similar. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM tablename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update t set date2=str_to_date(date2, '%d.%m.%Y'), date3=str_to_date(date3,'%d.%m.%Y');
alter table t modify date2 date;
alter table t modify date3 date;
```

Comment: Except that it's date2 and date3, not date1 and date2. Also, just to be sure, I would add a WHERE date2 LIKE (or maybe even a regexp?), and after the update I'd verify that no tuples are left with invalid dates. One problem with a string field is that it can blithely accept 32.15.2015, and we do not know what checks were made by the front-end.

Comment: @Iserni, about column names, true - edited.  About error handling, you're right, but I don't think SO answers are meant to solve the entire engineering problem at hand, just give the basic answer of "how do I do X".  I would assume the poster would do their own error and exception handling, and not expect answers to provide all that.  Plus, producing "0000-00-00" in the cases you mention might be the right thing to do anyway...

Comment: Totally agree on... *almost all*. Your point on 0000-00-00 is well taken. Also, I concur that we *can't* be expected to supply comprehensive answer and detail every nuance; perversely, the more we tried, the more we'd be taken to task for those points we did not address. I would still at least mention the one or two most obvious next steps or stumbling blocks (at this point, I might as well come clean and confess that by "most obvious" I mean "*having happened to me, more than once*").

Comment: I tested @e.dan 's suggestion and it worked perfectly! Error handling is a bit out of my reach at the moment, but a quick glance at the db after the update confirms that all the data was converted into my desired format. Thank you!!

Comment: Maybe I was a little quick there, some fields came up with 1970-01-01. Probably fields that had no data to start with. Any suggestion on how to skip these blank fields when doing the conversion?

Comment: Iserni had some ideas of adding a WHERE clause to validate the dates before converting - look into something like `WHERE date2 RLIKE '...'` using an appropriate regexp.  I am not sure what inputs would give `1970-01-01` - in my tests I mostly got `0000-00-00` or `NULL` so you will have to perform some queries on the tables to find out what input is causing that...

Comment: OK, gonna try my way forward with a WHERE clause and see if I can come up with a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can update the columns and use string functions:

```
update t
    set date2 = concat_ws('-', left(date2, 4), right(date2, 2), substr(date2, 4, 2)),
        date3 = concat_ws('-', left(date3, 4), right(date3, 2), substr(date3, 4, 2));
```

After you do this, you can even alter the types of the columns:

```
alter table modify date2 date;
alter table modify date3 date;
```

EDIT:

The actual format is dd.mm.yyyy rather than mm.dd.yyyy, so:

```
update t
    set date2 = concat_ws('-', left(date2, 4), substr(date2, 4, 2), right(date2, 2)),
        date3 = concat_ws('-', left(date3, 4), substr(date3, 4, 2), right(date3, 2));
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for contributing! I tested out your suggestion, but got some weird numbers in the columns. Not the MySQL expert, so don't know why. Afterwards I tested @e.dan 's suggestion and that did the trick, so I'm going for that one. Thank you again!

Comment: @ChrVik . . . This didn't work because I thought the format was mm.dd.yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

So first I'd suggest to convert the strings into a proper format (but keeping them as strings) like so:

```
update mytable set date2 = cast(str_to_date(date2, '%d.%m.%Y') as char(10)), 
                   date3 = cast(str_to_date(date3, '%d.%m.%Y') as char(10));
```

I'm not really sure whether the `cast(... as char(10))` is really neccessary. Then, in a second step change the column's datatypes:

```
alter table mytable modify date2 date;
alter table mytable modify date3 date;
```