# MySQL date_format and date ranges

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to generate a MySQL query that would display records between a specific date range.

Catering for a predominantly British userbase I have to format dates in a day-month-year manner.

As a result, I am storing dates as follows:

```
$timestamp = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
```

Now I am trying to run a MySQL query to return results between a set date range. *Time of day isn't so much of an issue for this specific query.*

I have come up with the following which doesn't seem to generate any results.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '01-01-2015 00:00:00' AND '31-12-2015 23:59:00'
```

I have ensured that `date_format` contents matches the same values of php `date()` variable yet it still doesn't display anything!

It might be worth noting that the timestamp column is set to be a `varchar(255)` for type.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: What is the format of the data in the timestamp column? Is it something like `NOW()` or  `unixtime` ?  Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose the right percentage!. Use `%m` instead of `%c`. `%m` is zero-padded (as you need it, i.e. `01` - `12`) whereas `%c` is not (i.e. `1` - `12`).

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for details.

---

### Update:

Sorry, the above is not true, as you store your dates as strings. I answered too quickly.

The problem is that you are comparing strings. So '14-02-2017' is before '24-12-2015'. Thus you have to convert your string into a date_time value as well:

```
str_to_date(`timestamp`, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Then you have to compare this with the values given, converted to the type date_time:

```
... where str_to_date(`timestamp`, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') 
  between str_to_date('01-01-2015 00:00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
      and str_to_date('31-12-2015 23:59:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

However, I would strongly suggest that you store your date in DATE_TIME columns and only convert them during INSERT (with STR_TO_DATE) and SELECT (with DATE_FORMAT).

Comment: Apologies, I was actually using `%m` but rather copies in the "older" version. Using `%m` still doesn't return any rows.

Comment: Yes, I see. My answer is wrong because you store your dates as strings, right? Wait a moment, I'll fix it.

Comment: Yes, I am storing as a string. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the constant updates.

Using:

`SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(`timestamp`, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') FROM table` converts the strings to dates for me.

Comment: @Codingmedic Yes, true. That's what my updated answer counts on: _Convert all three strings that look like dates into real dates and let MySQL compare them._

Comment: That works great! Thank you so much. I shall bear that in mind for future works and will attempt to convert the current entries into new columns for easier comparisons.

Comment: @Codingmedic You're welcome. To see how it works look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35537684/5830574

Answer (score 0):

replace your with this one:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s') 
BETWEEN '01-01-2015 00:00:00' AND '31-12-2015 23:59:00'
```

Comment: Sadly that also returns 0 results.

Comment: can provide with table structure and demo data